# Categorical equivalences and essentially commutating squares

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let's take four categories $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B},\mathcal{C}$, and \mathcal{D}. We will assume the existence of equivalences between them as laid out in the following diagram:
[image]

Can it happen that such a diagram does not essentially commute. What is a good illustrative example of this happening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens already with sets, no need to move to categories. Take all four categories to be $\mathbf{2}$ (viewed as the discrete category with two objects if you prefer) and take all but one of the above equivalences to be the identity. Choose the canonical equivalence swapping the two objects (essentially, negation) for the remaining equivalence.

One of the composites is then the identity while the other is the unique involution and, given that the categories are discrete, the diagram does not commute, essentially or otherwise.